# Grape: dynamic prefix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-grape

I have api set up like this:

```
class Dashboard < Api
  def self.inherited(subclass)
    super
    subclass.instance_eval do
      prefix 'dashboard'
      #...
    end
  end

  def self.company_id(path)
    ':company_id' + path
  end

  helpers do
    def current_company
      @current_company ||= Company.find(params[:company_id]) if params[:company_id]
    end
  end
end
```

Problem: I inherit class `Employee` from `Dashboard`, and what I want to achieve: resource, which inherits from `Dashboard`, should be accessed by it's namespace `'/dashboard/companies/:company_id/employees'`, with `current_company` working correct.

I feel tiring each time to provide full route instead of `namespace` convenience:

```
get 'companies/:company_id/employees'
#...
end
```

But this won't give result needed:

```
namespace :companies do
  namespace :employees do
  ...
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I undertand, you're looking for dynamic namespace, isn't it? You can define dynamic namespaces using a string instead of just a symbol. In the given string, each `:something` part indicates a parameter, same thing as what you may be used to in Rails or Sinatra routes syntax. In the endpoints, you'll then be able to access `params[:something]` as you usually do.

For instance, in your case, you might use something like this :

```
namespace 'companies/:company_id' do
  namespace :employees do
    get do
      # Will respond with the available params (containing :company_id)
      body params
    end
  end
end
```